# Adding quotes to MySQLdump using Sed

Tags: mysql, regex, sed

I am attempting to use sed to add quotes around decimal values in a mysql dump. The lines follow the format below:

```
INSERT INTO .... 'LastName', 1356.183);
```

I am trying to encapsulate the last value (in this case 1356.183) in quotes, which would result in the following:

```
INSERT INTO .... 'LastName', '1356.183');
```

So far I have tried variations on the following sed command with no luck:

```
sed -i '.bak' "s/, \(\d+.\d+\))/, '\1')/g" test.txt
```

Any recommendations for the regex I should be using? Thank you!

Comment: Try with `sed -i '.bak' "s/\(\d+.\d+\)/'\1'/g" test.txt`

Comment: Why do you need to quote numbers?  The `INSERT` should work fine with or without the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

VERY few tools will recognize `\d` as representing a digit and `+` is an ERE metacharacter, not BRE as sed supports by default. Just use `[0-9]` instead of `\d` and escape the `+` to activate it as an ERE metacharacter in a POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+/'\''&'\''/' file
INSERT INTO .... 'LastName', '1356.183');
```

I also escaped the `.` to deactivate it's metacharacter properties, and fixed your quoting (to avoid tripping over unexpected consequences, **never** use double quotes around any script - always use single quotes and terminate them **only** around any part you need the shell to be able to expand, e.g. you should do `sed 's/'"$var"'/whatever/'`, not `sed "s/$var/whatever/"`).